# Gatsby createPages with GraphQL returns Object: null prototype when Graphiql returns a string

Tags: graphql, gatsby, strapi

I'm setting up createPages in Gatsby using the slug pulled through Graphql from Strapi.

Here's my query:

```
query {
      allStrapiPosts {
        nodes {
          slug
        }
      }
    }
```

GraphiQL returns:

```
{
  "data": {
    "allStrapiPosts": {
      "nodes": [
        {
          "slug": "/pizza-struggles-today"
        },
        {
          "slug": "/raining-in-paradise"
        },
        {
          "slug": "/blog-title"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

My gatsby-node.js:

```
const path = require("path")

exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  const { data } = await graphql(`
    query {
      allStrapiPosts {
        nodes {
          slug
        }
      }
    }
  `)
  console.log(data)

  data.allStrapiPosts.nodes.forEach(({ node }) => {
    createPage({
      path: `blog${node.slug}`,
      component: path.resolve("./src/Templates/Post-Template.js"),
      context: {
        slug: node.slug,
      },
    })
  })
}
```

Here's the errors from the terminal:

```
[Object: null prototype] {
  allStrapiPosts: [Object: null prototype] {
    nodes: [
      [Object: null prototype],
      [Object: null prototype],
      [Object: null prototype]
    ]
  }
}

 ERROR #11321  PLUGIN

"gatsby-node.js" threw an error while running the createPages lifecycle:

Cannot read property 'slug' of undefined

  17 |   data.allStrapiPosts.nodes.forEach(({ node }) => {
  18 |     createPage({
> 19 |       path: `blog${node.slug}`,
     |                         ^
  20 |       component: path.resolve("./src/Templates/Post-Template.js"),
  21 |       context: {
  22 |         slug: node.slug,

File: gatsby-node.js:19:25



  TypeError: Cannot read property 'slug' of undefined

  - gatsby-node.js:19
    /Users/jeffstahlnecker/Developer/mxc-blog/gatsby-node.js:19:25

  - Array.forEach

  - gatsby-node.js:17 Object.exports.createPages
    /Users/jeffstahlnecker/Developer/mxc-blog/gatsby-node.js:17:29

  - task_queues.js:94 processTicksAndRejections
    internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5


failed createPages - 0.046s
```

My queries in other locations in Gatsby work well. For example I have a similar query creating a list of blog posts, that works without a problem.

Spent a few hours trying to troubleshoot this one last night. Any and all help is appreciated.

From gastby-config.js:

```
{
      resolve: `gatsby-source-strapi`,
      options: {
        apiURL: `https://cms.mxc.org:443`,
        queryLimit: 1000, // Default to 100
        contentTypes: [`posts`],
        //If using single types place them in this array.
        // singleTypes: [`home-page`, `contact`],
        // Possibility to login with a strapi user, when content types are not publically available (optional).
        loginData: {
          identifier: "",
          password: "",
        },
      },
    },
```

Comment: How does `gatsby-source-strapi` in your `gatsby-config.js` look like? Are you positive you want to work with `nodes` and not `edges { node { slug } }`?

Comment: `forEach(( node ) `?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring rather ... ... but do you find there that `{node}` is trying to extract `node` from iterated element instead of using whole element as `node` ?

Comment: Yes you're right @xadm. I was suggesting that the OP reads `Array.forEach` docs because it should then be obvious that there's no need to attempt to access `node.node` in order to get to `slug`.

Comment: copy/paste problem ... usually you start from error source `slug` ... OP should [looking at source] "translate it" into "`node` is undefined" and ask himself "why `node` is undefined?" ... check `node` declaration ... looks almost normal, almost is not enough ;)

Comment: @xadm that was it! Didn't see it - and thanks for the additional documentation.